# Shell: delete every second match against a regex in a file

Tags: regex, awk, sed, gawk

Say I have come up with a regex matching a piece of data; the regex contains 2 `sed` groups (sub-expressions enclosed in `(` and `)`).  Also say that this regex is duplicated 9 times to match a whole line.  The problem I am facing is how to delete (in an elegant way) every second match against the regex.

Comment: Please add an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the following string and want to remove the occurrences of `bar`:

```
foo bar foo bar foo bar
```

You can use the following `sed` command, note the option `g` which makes the substitution happen as many times as possible:

```
sed -r 's/([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)/\1/g' <<< 'foo bar foo bar foo bar'
```

Output: `foo foo foo`.

However this would not work with a string where the number of words is not even. I would make the second capturing group optional using the `*` quantifier to make the above commmand even work with such strings:

```
sed -r 's/([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)*/\1/g' <<< 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo'
```

Output: `foo foo foo foo`.

Comment: Good idea! Out of curiosity, how would you preserve only those matches against regex whose indices follow a more irregular pattern? I.e. how would you preserve matches 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, etc.?

Comment: Can you give a full example? Including the input and the expected output?

Comment: Use a `CSV` parser to handle CSV. This not a job for a regex (as you see). `Python`, `Perl` or even `PHP` or whatever all have lib functions to read and parse CSV files.

Comment: An aside: `[a-z]` can contain the upper case letter `X` (and many more - if you don't know why, google `locale` and `character class`) so `[[:lower:]]` is preferred.

Comment: @EdMorton It was just an example in this case, I don't even know the exact input data, but thanks for the hint! Will use `[[:lower:]]` when I *really* want to match lowercase characters. Especially in German (for example) it is important..