# Extract columns from a CSV file using Linux shell commands

Tags: regex, csv, awk, sed, gawk

I need to "extract" certain columns from a CSV file. The list of columns to extract is long and their indices do not follow a regular pattern. So far I've come up with a regular expression for a comma-separated value but I find it frustrating that in the RHS side of sed's substitute command I cannot reference more than 9 saved strings. Any ideas around this?

Note that comma-separated values that contain a comma must be quoted so that the comma is not mistaken for a field delimiter. I'd appreciate a solution that can handle such values properly. Also, you can assume that no value contains a new line character.

Comment: How about using the `cut` command?

Comment: How do you know which columns to extract? Oh, or is the set of indices the same for each line but the set is "random"? `cut` or `awk` may be of use here if you can't use an actual `csv` tool.

Comment: Always, at a a minimum, provide sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
$ cat file
a,"b,c",d,e

$ awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' '{print $2}' file
"b,c"
$ awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' '{print $3}' file
d

$ cat file
a,"b,c",d,e,"f,g,h",i,j

$ awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' -vOFS=, -vcols="1,5,7,2" 'BEGIN{n=split(cols,a,/,/)} {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", $(a[i]), (i<n?OFS:ORS)}' file
a,"f,g,h",j,"b,c"
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content for details. I doubt if it'd handle escaped double quotes embedded in a field, e.g. `a,"b""c",d` or `a,"b\"c",d`.

See also [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001) for how to parse CSVs with awk in general.

Comment: While I still think a fully fledged CSV parser would be the right tool for that, this answer is great! Never knew about `FPAT`

Comment: FPAT is new in gawk 4.*. If you don't have it you can do the same thing with a loop and match()+substr().

Comment: It would get a little more complicated if the input would be `a,"b,\"c\"",d,e,"f,g,h",i,j`. The regex should look like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2039820/171318) . Also still the solution supports the `,` as the delimiter only. What if you support multiple delimiters and the input would look like `a,b;c` ? Imo, a stable solution needs the delimiter as input argument, it cannot guess it. I guess this can be even proved by math.

Comment: Right, I mentioned at the end of the answer that it probably couldn't support embedded escaped quotes. To be robust, you'd also need a copy of the "standard" that defines the "CSV" language you are using. Trying to write a general CSV parser is like trying to write an Algol-like-language parser. Its a losing battle if you don't have a BNF for the SPECIFIC Algol-like-language you are trying to parse (C, awk, Java, pascal, Ada,....). IMHO if you have a "CSV" file that you KNOW has one delimiter and no embedded quotes or newlines, may as well keep the solution cheap and cheerful too.

Comment: Oh, I've overseen that you already mentioned that problems can arise if there are embedded double quotes in the data!

Comment: Regarding escape quotes: Maybe replacing all \" with say "__QUOTE__" prior to awk - ```cat source.csv | | sed 's/\\"/__QUOTE__/' | awk ... | sed 's/__QUOTE__/\\"/'``` 

Can be also done with gsub() inside AWK...

Comment: @elixon yeah there's lots of options. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001 for how to parse CSVs with awk in general and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35708616/1745001 for how to create/use temporary strings that can't be present in the input (if/when using a simple `\n` isn't an option within awk) rather than hoping `__QUOTE__` or any other string doesn't exist in  the input.

Answer (score 1):

CSV is not that easy to parse like it might look in the first place. 
This is because there can be a plenty of different delimiters or fixed column widths to separate the data, and also the data may contain the delimiter itself (escaped).

Like I already told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703702/shell-delete-every-second-match-against-a-regex-in-a-file/29703996#comment47544660_29703996) I would use a programming language which supports a CVS library for that.

Use

- [`Python`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)
- [`Perl`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm)
- [`Ruby`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)
- [`PHP`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)
- or even [`C`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c).

Comment: Don't forget the joys of having embedded linefeeds in a field.

Answer (score 0):

Fully fledged CSV parsers such as Perl's `Text::CSV_XS` are purpose-built to handle that kind of weirdness.
I provided sample code within my answer here:  [parse csv file using gawk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314384/parse-csv-file-using-gawk/33380831#33380831)

Answer (score 0):

There is command-line `csvtool` available - https://colin.maudry.com/csvtool-manual-page/

`# apt-get install csvtool`