# how to find a search term in source code

Tags: c++, c, grep

I'm looking for a way to search for a given term in a project's C/C++ code, while ignoring any occurrences in comments and strings.

As the code base is rather large, i am searching for a way to *automatically* identify the lines of code matching my search term, as they need manual inspection.

If possible I'd like to perform the search on my linux system.

## background

the code base in question is a realtime signal processing engine with a large number of 3rd party plugins. plugins are implemented in a variety of languages (mostly C, but also C++ and others; currently I only care for those two), no standards have been enforced.

our code base currently uses the built-in type `float` for floating-point numbers and we would like to replace that with a `typedef` that would allow us to use doubles.
we would like to find all occurrences of `float` in the actual code (ignoring legit uses in comments and printouts).

What complicates things furthermore, is that there are some (albeit few) *legit* uses of `float` in the code payload (so we are really looking for a way to identify all places that require manual inspection, rather than run some automatic search-and-replace.)

the code also contains C-style static casts to `(float)`, so relying on compiler warnings to identify type mismatches is often not an option.

the code base consists of more than 3000 (C and C++) files accumulating about 750000 lines of code.

the code is cross-platform (linux, osx, w32 being the main targets; but also freebsd and similar), and is compiled with the various native compilers (gcc/g++, clang/clang++, VisualStudio,...).

## so far...

so far I'm using something ugly like:

```
 grep "\bfloat\b" | sed -e 's|//.*||' -e 's|"[^"]*"||g' | grep "\bfloat\b"
```

but I'm thinking that there *must* be some better way to search only payload code.

Comment: What is your code doing? What is its size? What compiler & platform? Please **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: Depending on how large your codebase is, I might just do it manually with emacs. Otherwise I might just replace all of them and fix the spurious comments later. I'm lazy, though. :)

Comment: BTW C/C++ does not exist. A given translation unit is coded for C++ (then choose at least the C++11 standard) or for C (choose C11 if possible, or at least C99)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch while i don't understand why it is of use to know the compilers used for compiling my C and  C++ files, i have added that information. i am at a complete loss why the C-standard (or C++-standard) should be of any relevance.

Comment: Because if you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you can customize it with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (but if you use some other compiler you cannot use MELT). Also, there is no such language as C/C++, that was my point. At last, if coding in C++ in 2016, I strongly suggest to code for C++11 at least (which is a very different language than its predecessors)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch updated the question to hopefully answer those points; hopefully i could also clarify what i meant with "C/C++"

Comment: My feeling is that MELT is definitely worthwhile using in your case. But being the author of MELT, I am biased.

Comment: Depends on your editor/IDE. GCC and VIM support "ctags", as do several linux IDEs. in VIM you can use `ctrl-]` or `g ctrl-]` to go to the symbol under the cursor. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags

Comment: Also, several IDEs have functionality to do exactly this, e.g. Visual Studio's Refactor>Rename. Personally I use Whole Tomato's Visual AssistX and I've done something like this a number of times on much larger code bases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO there is a good answers on a similar question at "Unix & Linux":

> grep works on pure text and does not know anything about the
>   underlying syntax of your C program. Therefore, in order not search
>   inside comments you have several options:
>
> 1. Strip C-comments before the search, you can do this using gcc
>      -fpreprocessed -dD -E yourfile.c For details, please see [Remove comments from C/C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394017/remove-comments-from-c-c-code)
> 2. Write/use some hacky half-working scripts like you have already found
>      (e.g. they work by skipping lines starting with // or /*) in order to
>      handle the details of all possible C/C++ comments (again, see the
>      previous link for some scary testcases). Then you still may have false
>      positives, but you do not have to preprocess anything.
> 3. Use more advanced tools for doing "semantic search" in the code. I
>      have found "coccigrep": http://home.regit.org/software/coccigrep/ This
>      kind of tools allows search for some specific language statements
>      (i.e. an update of a structure with given name) and certainly they
>      drop the comments.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33136/158220

Although it doesn't completely cover your "not in strings" requirement.

Answer (score 3):

It might practically depend upon the size of your code base, and perhaps also on the editor you are usually using. I am suggesting to use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) (if possible on Linux with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler...)

For a small to medium size code (e.g. less than 300KLOC), I would suggest using the [`grep` mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html) of Emacs. Then (assuming you have bound the `next-error` Emacs function to some key, perhaps with `(global-set-key [f10] 'next-error)` in your `~/.emacs`...) you can quickly scan every occurrence of `float` (even inside strings or comments, but you'll skip very quickly such occurrences...). In a few hours you'll be done with a medium sized source code (and that is quicker than learning how to use a new tool).

For a large sized code (millions of lines), it might be worthwhile to customize some static analysis tool or compiler. You could use [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to customize your GCC compiler on Linux. Its [`findgimple` mode](http://gcc-melt.org/tutousemelt.html) could be inspirational, and perhaps even useful (you probably want to find all Gimple assignments targeting a `float`)

BTW, you probably don't want to replace *all* occurrences -but only most of them- of the `float`  type with `double` (probably suitably `typedef`-ed...), because very probably you are using some external (or standard) functions *requiring* a `float`.

The [CADNA](http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/cadna/) tool might also be useful, to help you estimate the precision of results (so help you deciding when using `double` is sensible).

Using semantical tools like [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), [CADNA](http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/cadna/), [Coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/), [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) (or perhaps [Fluctuat](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~putot/fluctuat.html), or [Coccigrep](http://home.regit.org/software/coccigrep/) mentioned in [g0hl1n's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35700515/841108)) would give more precise or relevant results, at the expense of having to spend more time (perhaps days!) in learning and customizing the tool.

Answer (score 1):

The robust way to do this should be with `cscope` (http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) in line-oriented mode using the `find this C symbol` option but I haven't used that on a variety of C standards so if that doesn't work for you or if you can't get `cscope` then do this:

```
find . -type f -print |
while IFS= read -r file
do
    sed 's/a/aA/g; s/__/aB/g; s/#/aC/g' "$file" |
    gcc -P -E - |
    sed 's/aC/#/g; s/aB/__/g; s/aA/a/g' |
    awk -v file="$file" -v OFS=': ' '/\<float\>/{print file, $0}'
done
```

The first `sed` replaces all hash (`#`) and `__` symbols with unique identifier strings, so that the preprocessor doesn't do any expansion of #include, etc. but we can restore them after preprocessing.

The `gcc` preprocesses the input to strip out comments.

The second `sed` replaces the hash-identifier string that we previously added with an actual hash sign.

The `awk` actually searches for `float` within word-boundaries and if found prints the file name plus the line it was found on. This uses GNU awk for word-boundaries `\<` and `\>`.

The 2nd sed's job COULD be done as part of the awk command but I like the symmetry of the 2 seds.

Unlike if you use `cscope`, this sed/gcc/sed/awk approach will NOT avoid finding false matches within strings but hopefully there's very few of those and you can weed them out while post-processing manually anyway.

It will not work for file names that contain newlines - if you have those you can put the body in a script and execute it as `find .. -print0 | xargs -0 script`.

Modify the gcc command line by adding whatever C or C++ version you are using, e.g. `-ansi`.

Comment: One caveat is that this does not prevent expansion of builtin macros with a single underscore (.e.g. `#define _LP64`) or that don't have underscores (e.g. `#define linux`)

Comment: @hugomg yes it does, see the `s/#/aC/g` in the first sed script that would convert `#define anything` to `aCdefine anything` before `gcc` sees it (or just try it).

Comment: Not in this case because `_LP64` and `linux` are builtin macros that the preprocessor always expands. Sorry, it would probably have been clearer if I wrote the comment without the `#define` bit, because there is no `#define` here.

Comment: @hugomg Now I understand. I just found a reference to such apparently system-specific macros at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html#System-specific-Predefined-Macros which appears to be saying don't use those macros that don't start with 2 underscores (`We are slowly phasing out all predefined macros which are outside the reserved namespace. You should never use them in new programs`) and use the `__` equivalents instead, i.e. `__LP64__` and `__linux__` in this case.