# I want to skip pattern in comments between /* */ or whatever

Tags: git, grep, git-grep

I want to skip pattern in comments between `/* */` or whatever.
for example f:

```
My name is
/*
alex
nice man
*/
alex is a nice man
```

Command:

```
git grep "alex" f
```

Print only:

```
alex is a nice man
```

I prefer use with git grep.

Comment: I don't understand your answer @Cyrus

Answer (score 0):

`grep` stands for `g/re/p` i.e. Globally search for a Regular Expression and print the matching string. What you're trying to do is far beyond that simple statement so you should be using awk:

```
$ awk 'index($0,"/*"){f=1} index($0,"*/"){f=0} !f && /alex/{print}' file
alex is a nice man
```

While the above will work for the simple example you show, it will fail for other cases such as multiple comments on a line or comments at the start/end of a target line or comment delimiters in other constructs such as within strings.

If you have those cases (e.g. as you could in a C or similar program) then you shouldn't be trying to do this with a text processing tool, you need a language parser, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35708616/1745001